# Find object in ArrayList

Tags: java, java-6

I want to find a `LegalEntity` object in an `ArrayList`. The object can possibly be a different instance. I'm only interested in whether they represent the same value, i.e. they have the same primary key. All `LegalEntity` instances are created from database values by EJB:

```
List<LegalEntity> allLegalEntities = myEJB.getLegalEntityfindAll());
LegalEntity currentLegalEntity = myEJB.getLegalEntityfindById(123L);
```

My first naive idea never finds matches:

```
if (allLegalEntities.contains(currentLegalEntity)) {
}
```

I then thought that perhaps I need to create my own `equals()` method:

```
public boolean equals(LegalEntity other) {
    return legalEntityId.equals(other.legalEntityId);
}
```

But this method is not even being invoked. Is there a way to find an object in a list that doesn't involve looping?

*I'm learning Java so it might easily be some foolish misunderstanding on my side.*

Comment: you need to override the equals method, not overload it

Comment: You are correct with the equals method, but since you changed the method signature, your own equals method is not the method that is being called. You need to override `public boolean equals(Object other)` and define there what equality means in that case (you mentioned same primary key).

Comment: While `contains()` does use `equals(Object)`, your `equals(LegalEntity)` is not `equals(Object)`. Even so, overriding `equals(Object)` may not be the correct option, as equality is a difficult concept. You could just write a helper method with a for-loop in it to find it. You didn't really take the easy road in learning Java from EJB and Java 6.

Comment: With `public boolean equals(Object other)` it appears to work (`Object` doesn't have a `legalEntityId` property but I can force a cast inside the method). What edge cases can possibly bite my foot in the future?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález with that method, it won't work. You need to pass an object, in the equals method, check if it's an instance of LegalEntity, if not, return false, if so, cast

Comment: @Stultuske Sorry, I was a copy+paste error! I've edited my comment.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález what can be a nuissance in the future is that you implemented equals, without implementing hashCode

Comment: You may also need to override the hashCode() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but you need to **override** the method equals that accepts an `Object`:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    LegalEntity other = (LegalEntity) obj;
    // check if equals based one some properties
}
```

However you also need to override `hashCode`:

```java
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // return a unique int
}
```

So this might not be the easiest solution.

Another approach is to use `filter`:

```java
LegalEntity myLegalEntity = myEJB.getLegalEntityfindAll().stream()
                              .filter(legalEntity -> legalEntity.getProperty().equals("someting"))
                              .findAny()
                              .orElse(null);
```

More info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/find-list-element-java)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8 you can use streams:

```
List<LegalEntity> allLegalEntities = myEJB.getLegalEntityfindAll());
LegalEntity currentLegalEntity = allLegalEntities.stream().filter(entity -> entity.getId() == 123L).findFirst();
```